# To list 12 months in a query Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need your help, please.
I have a query to list a PDAs numbers and I need to sort this in twelve months. My query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(primeirodia_mes,'mm/yyyy') competencia,
'Suporte' tipo,
   (SELECT COUNT(tipo)
    FROM v_pdas_suporte_se
    WHERE TO_CHAR(primeirodia_mes,'mm/yyyy') = TO_CHAR(v_pdas_suporte_se.dt,'mm/yyyy')
AND tipo IN ( 'S','E')
) quantidade
FROM
  (SELECT To_Date( '01/'
    ||LPad(ID,2,0)
    ||'/'
    ||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy') ,'dd/mm/yyyy') primeirodia_mes
   FROM
    (SELECT LEVEL AS ID FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12    )
) contador
```

I need to list , for example, Oct/2014 to Oct/2015.

Comment: where is `ORDER BY` clause in your select statement ? Also, share your expected output with your current script output. This will help everyone to understand\.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for this:

```
WITH t AS    
    (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), - LEVEL+1) AS primeirodia_mes 
    FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 13)
SELECT 
    primeirodia_mes AS competencia, 
    'Suporte' tipo,
    COUNT(tipo)
FROM v_pdas_suporte_se
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN t ON primeirodia_mes = TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
GROUP BY primeirodia_mes;
```

Comment: Is solved. Perfect @Wernfried Domscheit .. Danke und haben Sie einen großen Tag. Thank you guys (@jWeaver and everybody).